# Using fillRect to draw a pixel is not smooth

Tags: html, canvas, rgb, pixel

My javascript code paints the wall with multiply blending. If I use fillRect it's faster but not smooth and putImageData is opposite of it and takes approximately 10 seconds to paint the image. For example left one is made with fillRect:

[image]

Code used in the left image;

```
context_paintLayer.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + pixel.data[0] + ',' + pixel.data[1] + ',' + pixel.data[2] + ',' + pixel.data[3] + ')';
context_paintLayer.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

Code used in the right image;

```
context_paintLayer.putImageData(pixel, x, y);
```

If you want, I can post the full code here. Thanks.

```
function applyPaint(selectedColor)
{
    var partitionImageData = context_partitionLayer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    var imageData = context_imageLayer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    var selectedColorRGB = selectedColor.split("-");

    for(var y = targetStartY; y < targetEndY; y++) 
    {
        for(var x = targetStartX; x < targetEndX; x++) 
        {
            var index = ((width * y) + x) * 4;

            var r = partitionImageData.data[index];
            var g = partitionImageData.data[index + 1];
            var b = partitionImageData.data[index + 2];
            var a = partitionImageData.data[index + 3];

            pixel.data[0] = (selectedColorRGB[0] * (imageData.data[index]+50)) / 255;
            pixel.data[1] = (selectedColorRGB[1] * (imageData.data[index + 1]+50)) / 255;
            pixel.data[2] = (selectedColorRGB[2] * (imageData.data[index + 2]+50)) / 255;
            pixel.data[3] = (a * (imageData.data[index + 3])) / 255;

            if(isInPart(r, g, b) == 1)
            {
                paint(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}

function paint(x, y)
{
    context_paintLayer.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + pixel.data[0] + ',' + pixel.data[1] + ',' + pixel.data[2] + ',' + pixel.data[3] + ')';
    context_paintLayer.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);    
    //context_paintLayer.putImageData(pixel, x, y);
}

function isInPart(r, g, b, targetPart) {

    if ((r >= targetRMin && r <= targetRMax) && (g >= targetGMin && g <= targetGMax) && (b >= targetBMin && b <= targetBMax)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, show more code please. For your left image code, for each point : 1) you are creating a string  + 2) you require a color string decode, so no wonder it is slow. What about drawing points in a temporary imageData sized like the image, then draw the whole imageData at once ?

Comment: @GameAlchemist I updated the code. The problem is that the browser is not responding while the applyPaint function is working.

Comment: Is the size of the various canvases fixed ?

Comment: @GameAlchemist Yes they are all the same like layers.

Comment: i mean they won't change during the App 's lifetime ?

Comment: No they won't change.

Comment: @Cem - of course the browser doesn't respond during applyPaint - JS is not multi-threaded.

Comment: I know JS is not able to multithread but rect is working much faster than putImageData.

Comment: PS : could you show your isInPart code ??

Comment: If you're interested, i can describe a way to process that will, for a given fixed image, allow you to recolor in real-time.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by 'real-time'. Of course I'm interested in another way.

Comment: 'real time' means that it will take less time than the brain can notice -or something like that :-) - see my edit for the gpu way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you 'paint' directly into an imageData during your loop, then do one single puImageData at the end.
And Since your canvas sizes are not changing, you might cache the arrays to avoid the costs of creation / disposal.
The code below should be waay faster.
I don't know enough of your requirements to know, for instance, if the image is changing and thus need to be getImageDataed (:-)) on each call, but you'll get the idea :

```
function applyPaint() {
    var partitionImageData = context_partitionLayer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    var partitionData = partitionImageData.data;
    var sourceImageData = context_imageLayer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    var sourceData = sourceImageData.data;
    var destImageData = context_paintLayer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    var destData = destImageData.data;

    applyPaint = function (selectedColor) {
        var selectedColorRGB = selectedColor.split("-");
        var index = 0;
        var selectedR = selectedColorRGB[0];
        var selectedG = selectedColorRGB[1];
        var selectedB = selectedColorRGB[2];
        // cache arrays for speed up
        var _partitionData = partitionData;
        var _sourceData = sourceData ;
        var _destData = destData;

        for (var y = targetStartY; y < targetEndY; y++) {
            for (var x = targetStartX; x < targetEndX; x++) {
                index = ((width * y) + x) << 2;
                var r = _partitionData[index];
                var g = _partitionData[index + 1];
                var b = _partitionData[index + 2];

                if (isInPart(r, g, b) == 1) {
                    var a = _partitionData[index + 3];
                    _destData[index] = (selectedR * (_sourceData[index] + 50)) >> 8;
                    _destData[index + 1] = (selectedG * (_sourceData[index + 1] + 50)) >> 8;
                    _destData[index + 2] = (selectedB * (_sourceData[index + 2] + 50)) >> 8;
                    _destData[index + 3] = (a * (_sourceData[index + 3])) >> 8;
                }
            }
        }
        context_paintLayer.putImageData(destImageData, 0, 0);
    }
    return applyPaint.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Edit : if you plan on updating the whole image each time, you can simplify the two for loops to :

```
  var pixelCount = width*height;
  var index = 0;
  while (pixelCount--) {

    // process index 
    // ...

    index+=4;
  }
```

Edit 2 :

Here is a way to get, for a given image, real-time recoloring (meaning image rate is > 60 fps).
The idea is to have the gpu compute for you by using composite modes / blending modes.

http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/

Step 1) 
Re-process your partition image to get a partition mask canvas, that will contains full white
for pixels matching your criteria, and full black for pixels not matching.

It would be built like

```
• build new canvas to store the partition mask.
• for each pixel of the partition image : 
         if (condition on the partition data r,g,b )
             partitionMaskImageData[ ...r and g and b and a ] = 255  
         else
             partitionMaskImageData[ ...r and g and b and a ] = 0
```

Now, build a static temporary canvas for your operations, and
each time you want to change color :

```
   1) clear the temp canvas.  
    2) draw the partition mask on the temp canvas.  
    3) draw the image on the temp canvas using mode 'destination-in'.   
    4) add 50 to all rgb : draw a rect  of color 'rgb(50,50,50) using mode 'lighter'.    
    5) fill a rect with your selected color using mode 'multiply'  
        --> now the temp canvas is ready.
    6) draw the original image on destination canvas   
    7) draw the temp canvas on the destination canvas.
```

Little trouble here is that not all Browser support 'multiply', but quite some do as you can see here http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas-blending.

Still i bet that the update will take far less than 1ms (on desktop).

Comment: Works almost immediately. Thank you! Using putImageData too much is not a good idea then.

Comment: @Cem : you're welcome. In fact i did not see that you want to update a rect, not the whole image on each time. See my edit for the fix, in which i also added a tiny boost by caching arrays.